# Java getting blank image using PDFBox image conversion

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, pdf-reader

i'm trying to make a simple pdf reader with Java and PDFBox;
In my code i convert the pages in *ImageIcon* and then i set it in a *JLabel*, the *JLabel* is added to a *ScrollPane* so at the end i have a nice scrollable page.

For the first page (loaded by the constructor) it works fine, but when i try to load another page from the *actionPerformed* function the result is a blank page, even if the try-catch give no error.

```
public class PDFreader extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    List<PDPage> Pages;
    int CurrentPage = 0;

    JButton Back, Next;
    JLabel Info, LabelImage;

    public PDFreader(String Title, PDDocument doc) throws IOException {

        this.setTitle(Title);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        PDPage pag = (PDPage) Pages.get(CurrentPage);

        ImageIcon PageImage = new ImageIcon(pag.convertToImage());
        LabelImage = new JLabel(PageImage);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(LabelImage);

        Back = new JButton("Previous page");
        Next = new JButton("Next page");

        Back.setEnabled(false);
        if(Pages.size()==1)
            Next.setEnabled(false);

        Back.addActionListener(this);
        Next.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        p.add(Back);
        p.add(Next);

        Info = new JLabel("Page 1 of "+ Pages.size(), SwingConstants.CENTER);

        getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(Info, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }




    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Ev) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(Ev.getSource() == Next) {
            CurrentPage++;
        }
        if(Ev.getSource() == Back) {
            CurrentPage--;
        }

        if(CurrentPage == 0)
            Back.setEnabled(false);
        else
            Back.setEnabled(true);

        if(CurrentPage == Pages.size()-1)
            Next.setEnabled(false);
        else
            Next.setEnabled(true);          


        try {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) Pages.get(CurrentPage);
            ImageIcon PageImage = new ImageIcon(page.convertToImage());
            LabelImage.setIcon(PageImage);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();        

        }

        Info.setText("Pagina "+(CurrentPage+1)+" di "+ Pages.size());

    }
}
```

Is there a problem because i'm trying to load it in the *actionPerformed*? Any other tips?

Comment: From a "dry" read I don't see any problems, except that the first page you render is the 4th one (the "3" in the code). Did you test running the PDFReader command line application? https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html#pdfReader This just to be sure that there isn't a page in that PDF that renders to blank because of a bug in the 1.8 version.

Comment: Sorry for the "3" in the code, it was a test to verify what you later asked; It loads well all the pages I ask the first time, but when i try to load another page from a JButton action it gives me a blank one.

Comment: Debug ideas: What happens if you try 1) to save the BufferedInmage that you pass to "new ImageIcon()" with ImageIO.write() ? 2) what happens if you pass a BufferedImage containing only a single color to "new ImageIcon()" ? This would answer whether you actually get a useful image from the convertToInage(), and whether your display method works properly (You hint at this yourself in the last comment, but I'm more a PDFBox guy than a Java GUI guy)

Comment: I just managed to get your code to work (added a main) and have no trouble. However the image is not "fit in window", you might want to adjust the resolution.

Comment: the ImageIo.write() saves the exact thing i saw in the program: correct image for the constructor and blank for the action one.

Comment: it works also when you change page? it's not possible...

Comment: Yes, I was able to go till the end. I'm going to sleep soon now; suggestion: either upload your PDF somewhere, or get a PDF on the web with several pages, test with that one and post the URL. Oh, and I used 1.8.8. to test, this is the latest version.

Comment: just tryed with this [masterpiece](http://slurm.schedmd.com/coding_style.pdf) ... same issues. I'm also using 1.8.8; you changed anything in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing the document too early, that is why. I was able to reproduce the effect you get by closing the document after calling

```
new PDFReader("Title", doc);
```

So one solution would be e.g. opening the document within the JPanel constructor instead of passing it as a parameter as you do now (pass the file instead), and close it when the JPanel is closing by adding this:

```
addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt)
    {
        try
        {
            document.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
        }
    }
});
```

document need to be a local final variable within your PDFReader class.